# Real Time Network questions are not updating

Tags: support, realtime-questions

I'm not getting the network questions updating, they freeze untill I refresh the page. I thought at one point that there had been no questions for an hour, until I refreshed.

I'm also not getting Rep change updates until I refresh the page - and once I've seen them and I refresh again, they reappear.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2 with Chrome 42.0.2311.152

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably related to the [current](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/599934236188090368) network problems.

[image: tweet about network problems]

The issue is that [outgoing packets](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3454597#3454597) get [dropped](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3454600#3454600), as explained by [Bret Copeland](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/231173/bret-copeland)

StackAuth.com was also affected, leading to issues with logging-on once logged out.

Comment: Yep, fixed now :)